# Search for duplicates of items in list within list

Tags: python, list, search, duplicates, output

Working on a basic project to simulate the life cycle of an organism using matplotlib. The organism's position is defined by list [x,y], and its position is randomly generated. Organism being the class

```
    for i in range(numorganisms):
        posX = random.randint(0,XMAX)
        posY = random.randint(0,YMAX)
        creatures.append(organism([posX,posY]))
```

There may be about 100 of these in the plot, meaning collisions will occur. I want to be able to search the list of creatures for instances where posX and posY are both equal, and then create a new list of those positions.

Answer (score 2):

You may easily do this:

```
existing = set()
for i in range(numorganisms):
    posX = random.randint(0,XMAX)
    posY = random.randint(0,YMAX)
    if (posX, posY) not in existing :
        creatures.append(organism([posX,posY]))
        existing.add( (posX, posY) )
    else :
        pass   # do something else
```

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you have some way to get the positions out of the instance of `organism`.

```
###############################
# This just recreates what I think you already have
import random
class organism:
    def __init__(self, l):
        self.l = l

XMAX = YMAX = 100
creatures = []
for i in range(100):
    posX = random.randint(0,XMAX)
    posY = random.randint(0,YMAX)
    creatures.append(organism([posX,posY]))
print(creatures)
###############################

# Determine if there are redundancies
positions = [x.l for x in creatures]
print(positions)
collisions = [i for i in positions if positions.count(i) > 1]
print(collisions)
```